# AMD kaveri not detecting my driver?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit

I have a **AMD Kaveri APU**, recently downloaded **[oibaf driver PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)**, but when I try to play any game I get a black screen or very slow 3D.

Any idea on how to fix?

```
 *-display NO RECLAMADO  
   descripción: VGA compatible controller
   producto: Kaveri [Radeon R7 Graphics]
   fabricante: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   id físico: 1
   información del bus: pci@0000:00:01.0
   versión: 00
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuración: latency=0
   recursos: memoria:c0000000-cfffffff memoria:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memoria:feb00000-feb3ffff memoria:feb40000-feb5ffff
```

***this is on ubuntu 16.04***

this is what I get with `glxinfo -i | grep render`

```
pablo@pablo:~$ glxinfo -i | grep render
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  44
  Current serial number in output stream:  47
pablo@pablo:~$
```

Comment: Anyone knows how to activate oibaf driver with kaveri apu?

Comment: Did you have a problem with the original, open-source drivers shipped with Ubuntu 16.04? Why did you installed the "optimized" ones?

Comment: I used the optimized because I want to play games with openGL 4.1

Comment: Have you followed all the instruction on the website you refer? There is plenty of configuration needed. It is not enough to just install. Finally, if the original worked (ruling out any defect in the hardware), then, this could perfectly be a bug. This is expected, given that you are dealing with latest drivers.